# Exoplayer NO Sound while streaming m3u8

Tags: android, streaming, exoplayer

im currently doing a streaming app but i got an issue with exployer, some of my video link are playing fine with sound, but some is not, here is the sample streaming link i have

```
http://202.57.43.60:8443/live/5748aabe4c9d661afbd7f4068248f664/99.m3u8
```

and here is my code:

```
BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
    playerView  = findViewById(R.id.movie_exo_player);
    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);
    simpleExoPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes
            .Builder().build());
    playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);
    DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "Exo2"), defaultBandwidthMeter);
    DefaultHlsExtractorFactory defaultHlsExtractorFactory = new DefaultHlsExtractorFactory(FLAG_ALLOW_NON_IDR_KEYFRAMES);
    MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .setExtractorFactory(defaultHlsExtractorFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(VIDEO_TEST_URL));

    LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(loopingSource);
    if(VIDEO_TEST_URL != null){
        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
```

any form of help is much appreciated

Comment: Most players do not like http streams rather than https ones - do you have an example that uses https that you can share as it may be easier to investigate. The problem you describe sounds like it may be codec or encryption related but hard to tell without more checking.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue using this same URL, if I play the URL directly in my Linux with MPV it plays with sound. But when in Android with Exo it won't, I looked for solutions and they say to use FFmpeg extensions in Exo. I tried that too, but no sound still. Here is my implemenation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67180781/no-suitable-media-source-factory-found-for-content-type-2-exo-player