# No suitable media source factory found for content type: 2 (Exo Player)

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm trying to play a stream with ExoPlayer.

I add ExoPlayer to Project by downloading it from Github in order to use FFmpeg Renderer extensions. Previously, I was using it by adding implementations in `app/build.gradle` and it was working.
But the stream didn't play the sound. Its codec wasn't supported by Exo. so I have to use FFmpeg extensions. To build and use extensions we have to go through the locally downloading method. But now this time, When I build and run the app it crashes with an error.

MyActivityLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.activities.ExoTest">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

MyActivityCode

```
class ExoTest : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mBinding: ActivityExoTestBinding
    private lateinit var player: SimpleExoPlayer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mBinding = ActivityExoTestBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mBinding.root)

        val streamURL = "http://202.57.43.60:8443/live/5748aabe4c9d661afbd7f4068248f664/99.m3u8"

        val defaultRenderersFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(this).setExtensionRendererMode(DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_ON)

        player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this, defaultRenderersFactory).build()

        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(streamURL)

        mBinding.videoView.player = player

        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)

        player.prepare()
        player.playWhenReady = true
        player.play()
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get

```
2021-04-20 09:17:07.561 4385-4385/com.johnrelly.livetv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.johnrelly.livetv, PID: 4385
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.johnrelly.livetv/com.johnrelly.livetv.view.activities.ExoTest}: java.lang.NullPointerException: No suitable media source factory found for content type: 2
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3408)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3547)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:140)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2080)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:264)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7581)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No suitable media source factory found for content type: 2
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Assertions.checkNotNull(Assertions.java:176)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.DefaultMediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(DefaultMediaSourceFactory.java:329)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.createMediaSources(ExoPlayerImpl.java:933)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImpl.setMediaItems(ExoPlayerImpl.java:365)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BasePlayer.setMediaItems(BasePlayer.java:49)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BasePlayer.setMediaItem(BasePlayer.java:34)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer.setMediaItem(SimpleExoPlayer.java:1320)
        at com.johnrelly.livetv.view.activities.ExoTest.onCreate(ExoTest.kt:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7805)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7794)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3378)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed I was missing this in app/build.gradle

```
implementation project(':exoplayer-library')
```

only this error is solved, the sound is still not playing.

Answer (score 4):

Similarly, I saw this issue with the newer (media3) version of `ExoPlayer` when trying to add subtitles. Needed to add a different `-hls` dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-common:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-hls:1.1.1"
    ...
}
```